# select defalaut value if row not exist AND select from multiple tables if row not exist in secont table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
Permission
|id|userID|canView|canEdit|
|--+------+-------+-------|
|1 |  0   | true  | false |  (my default value)
|2 |  1   | true  | true  |

Users
|id|name |
|--+-----|
|1 |Smith|
```

How select all rows from  Permission and add name column from users table like this

```
    |id|userID|canView|canEdit|name |
    |--+------+-------+-------+-----|
    |1 |  0   | true  | false |NULL | 
    |2 |  1   | true  | true  |Smith|
```

i try

```
SELECT p.* , u.name FROM `Permission` p ,`Users` u WHERE u.id = p.userID
```

but its only return

```
    |id|userID|canView|canEdit|name |
    |--+------+-------+-------+-----|
    |2 |  1   | true  | true  |Smith|
```

Comment: You may want to take a little time and learn about the different join types. Left, right, full OUTER, and Cross joins.  I've found the following beneficial in explaining them. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a `LEFT JOIN`, this will fill from the column from the right table with nulls if no match is found:

```
SELECT 
  p.* , 
  u.name 
FROM `Permission` p 
LEFT JOIN `Users` u 
ON p.userID = u.id
```